# How do I select with where column have two different value (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm learning SQL, I'm a bit complicated with a sentence that I have to do.

I need to get the accounts, which have these values in the same columns (KEY)

```
1133-1-1, 7095-1-1
```

Code:

```
SELECT cta 
FROM cargos 
WHERE key = '7095-1-1' AND key = '7021-233-1';
```

Expected result:

```
cta: 192568210
```

The result of this query is 0, but If I make the query to get the keys of an account, it shows them to me:

```
SELECT key 
FROM cargos 
WHERE cta = 192568210;
```

Result:

[image]

I use Oracle 11g.

Comment: The `AND` is wrong - you **cannot** have any rows that has **both values** for `key` at the same time.....

Answer (score 1):

use or instead of 'and'

```
SELECT cta FROM cargos where key = '7095-1-1' or key = '1133-1-1';
```

Answer (score 1):

The key cannot be `'7095-1-1'` **and** `'1133-1-1'`, because it can have only one value at the same time. But it can be `'7095-1-1'` **OR** `'1133-1-1'`.

The confusion arises from the fact that the condition does **not** specify which rows are returned (row1 **and** row2), but which condition each individual key must satisfy for a row to be returned.

```sql
SELECT cta FROM cargos where key = '7095-1-1' OR key = '1133-1-1';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `OR` as already mentioned. Another option is to use `IN`.
This will be much shorter and better readable if there are plenty of OR's otherwise.
For example:

```
SELECT cta FROM cargos 
WHERE key IN ('7095-1-1','7021-233-1','123','ABC');
```

will do the same as

```
SELECT cta FROM cargos
WHERE key = '7095-1-1'
OR key = '7021-233-1'
OR key = '123'
OR key = 'ABC';
```

For just two keys, it doesn't really matter which of these two options you choose.